# Raspberry pi 3 MIPI signal question

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I'm using Raspberry pi 3 and V2 camera.
I want to control the 4 cameras.
Two cameras are working but the other two are not.
It is a picture of two deferential pair signals compared using an oscilloscope.
What causes does a voltage difference in a deferential signal grow?

[image]

*Photo 1: Normal operation.*

[image]

*Photo 2: Abnormal operation.*

Answer (score 0):

The MIPI standard specifies two level of voltages:

One is I2C compatible and it is used to control the camera, read and write the internal registers. This is called the LS (Low speed) state.

The other is the HS state in which the signals work as a high speed differential signal. That is when the data is transported. That can go up to the GHZ range.

For all the details, e.g how the signals indicate a transfer from one state to the other, you should try to get you hands on the MIPI spec. But as many standards these day you probably have to pay to be part of a consortium to be allowed to have one.